# Can I add search hints to an html tag so that a browser's search button finds the text?

Tags: html

I have a list of telephones. I format those like so: 555-123-4567.

Users keep trying to use the search function of the browser but don't type the dashes or they copy-paste the phone number that doesn't have the dashes. Thus, they don't find the text they are looking for until they edit it and add the dashes.

This adds a little frustration to their experience.

My current solution is to add a transparent element next to the phone number so that the browser can find it when using the search function. But it feels dirty.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You don't control how the Client's Browser works when it comes to pressing `ctrl+f`..

Comment: And I don't mean to. I am looking for ways into tricking or leveraging something.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can come up with, is if you wrap each set of numbers in its own `<span>`, and then use CSS to apply the dashes for display (which seems reasonable, since the dashes are purely for visual presentation), for example:

```css
/* selects a <span> element that
   is an adjacent sibling to
   another <span> element; and
   styles the pseudo element (the
   ::before to present the hyphen
   character: */
span + span::before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<span>555</span><span>123</span><span>4567</span>
```

So far as I'm aware there's no API for providing 'hints' to a browser's search functionality, but the above approach works for me (Windows 10/Chrome 46) allows for the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find the relevant text when I enter the hyphen-separated numbers.

The caveat of this approach is, obviously, that should the user search for the numbers *with* the dashes included the browser won't find those. So unfortunately you'll need to find one presentation solution for a consistent UI, and try and educate your users how to search or provide obvious search functionality in your page fuelled by a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Of course, now if the user searches using dashes, *that* won't be found.

Comment: Indeed, I was just editing that caveat in as your comment popped up. :)